# angular.element("inputFieldId").focus() doesn't put focus in the input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

I have a small SPA using angular-ui-bootstrap to provide the tabs component.  The app mostly just displays data showing the operational status of an application, but one of the tabs has an input field that should get the focus when that tab is opened.

The controller for each tab component has a "tabOpened" and "tabClosed" function, which is called when that tab is opened or closed.

In the controller for the tab with the input field, I have the following:

```
$scope.tabOpened    = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element("handlerSearchInput").focus();
    });
};
```

It's worth disputing whether it's reasonable to do this in a controller, as opposed to engineering some sort of directive to make the "focus()" call, but that's not the issue I need to solve first.  My first problem is that this code doesn't actually work.  I can see it hit the breakpoint in the function when I open the tab, but the field doesn't get the focus.  There are no errors, it just doesn't work.

I've tested this in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular.element` takes either `string` - in which case it will create a new element, or a `jQuery` selector which will return an existing element

so you should use `angular.element("#handlerSearchInput").focus();`

([API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element))

Comment: Duh.  That was it.  Thanks.